# Zipping files with 7z.exe

Tags: batch-file, zip, 7zip

I have a folder that contains a batch file named zip.bat with the following code inside:

> for /d %%X in (*) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\"

The issue that i'm having with this bat is that it zips any folder inside the folder that contains the zip.bat but what I really want it to do is to zip text files not folders.

Can anyone guide me on what i'm doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Then tell it to zip text files. You are telling it to zip the folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear to me.

If you want to have each folder containing txt-files in a separate zip-file you can use:

```
for /d %%X in (*) do "C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a "%%X.zip" "%%X\*.txt"
```

If you want a single zip-file named  containing all txt-files (with folder structure) you can use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -r txtfiles-%date%.zip "*.txt"
```

If you want a single zip-file named  containing txt-files of the current folder where your cmd/batch file is located you can use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\7-Zip\7z.exe" a txtfiles-%date%.zip "*.txt"
```

Comment: I want to zip only the text files and not the folders.

Comment: What should I edi in the code so It can zip text files and not folders?

Comment: @Hereok, the first line of code he gave you is zipping text files. The second is also zipping text files.

Comment: it don't work?? please provide some more information. what kind of command did you enter? can yo provide the batch file? what kind of response do yo get? error /warning messages??

Comment: The firt code that Frank provided does exactly what I don't want it to do, zip folders. All I want the bat to do is zip text files, example if text file gets place in the same folder where the bat resides just zip the text file and done.

Comment: Then use suggestion 2 or 3